# C# - Display int value by inputting int name

Tags: c#, integer

say for example I want to create a very simple program that stored and displayed chemistry elements Mass numbers, how would do I display the int value by inputting the int name??

```
Console.Write("Element Symbol:");
Console.ReadLine();

int Li = 7;
int Be = 9;

Console.WriteLine("Mass Number:");
```

???? Sorry for the stupid questions but help is appreciated

Comment: Lithium has mass = 6.941, Beryllium has mass = 9.012182 so why do you use integers?

Comment: @Steve, Yeah I know, just for the sake of simplicity. As a way of messing around with C# I want to make an RFM calculator so just going to stick with whole numbers for the time being.

Answer (score 4):

It would be more appriopiate to have a mapping from Element symbol --> Mass. You should create a `Dictionary<string, int>` for that, that stores the mass for each element (the element's name is the key, the mass is the value). As pointed out by another comment, make the mass `float` or a `double` instead of an `int` if you desire.

```
private Dictionary<string, int> PeriodicTable =
    new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"Li", 5 },
        {"Be", 9 }
        //more elements..
    };

private int GetMass(string element)
{
    int value = 0;
    //Try to get the value
    if (PeriodicTable.TryGetValue(element, out value))
        return value;
    else //not found
        return -1;
}
```

If you find this too complicated, use a classical `switch` statement.

```
private int GetMass(string element)
{
    switch(element)
    {
        case "Li":
            return 5;
        case "Be":
            return 9;
        //..
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or a decimal instead of a double?

Comment: Good answer, but what's the point of using `TryGetValue` when you've already  checked that it has the key?

Comment: Right, that makes no sense. I should have used the return value of `TryGetValue()` directly. Code's edited.